# How to unpack a single variable tuple in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples

I have a tuple-

`('name@mail.com',)`.

I want to unpack it to get 'name@mail.com'.

How can I do so?

I am new to Python so please excuse.

Comment: If it will always have only one element u can use `indices` to get the element. `t[0]` where t is ur tuple

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the content? is it always single size tuple?

Comment: If you are this new, you are better off trying to follow a tutorial than asking every question you think of on Stack Overflow. The main Python website provides a tutorial that will cover quite a bit of ground: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html Specifically tuples are introduced here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tu = ('name@mail.com',)

str = tu[0]

print(str) #will return 'name@mail.com'
```

A tuple is a sequence type, which means the elements can be accessed by their indices.

Answer (score 35):

The full syntax for unpacking use the syntax for tuple literal so you can use

```
tu = ('name@mail.com',)
(var,) = tu
```

The following simplified syntax is allowed

```
var, = tu
```

Comment: Even though the question seems like an easy one, but actually "unpacking" is not the same as just picking the first index, so I would choose this as the actual answer as it answers what the title requested. (Even though OP might not have intended it)

Answer (score 7):

The prettiest way to get the first element and the last element of an `iterable` object like `tuple`, `list`, etc. would be to use the `*` feature not same as the `*` operator.

```py
my_tup = ('a', 'b', 'c',)

# Last element
*other_els, last_el = my_tup

# First element
first_el, *other_els = my_tup

# You can always do index slicing similar to lists, eg [:-1], [-1] and [0], [1:]

# Cool part is since * is not greedy (meaning zero or infinite matches work) similar to regex's *. 
# This will result in no exceptions if you have only 1 element in the tuple.
my_tup = ('a',)

# This still works
# Last element
*other_els, last_el = my_tup

# First element
first_el, *other_els = my_tup

# other_els is [] here
```

Comment: `('a')` is not a tuple, it resolves to `'a'`. A tuple with one element would be `('a',)`. But cool to know, `*other_els, last_el = 'a'` is working also.

Comment: I forgot to put a `,` at the end. Please don't use `('a')` even if you think that you are getting the right result, it's not right. Since strings are sliceable the `*rest, target` list explosion syntax works without errors. But if you use a longer string like `('abc')` this will break resulting in `rest = ['a', 'b']` and `target = 'c'`

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is just like a list but static, so just do :

```
('name@mail.com',)[0]
```